# Installing Kibana version compatible to Elasticsearch2.3.5 on windows

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

I have a Elasticsearch version `2.3.5` running on my local machine. I want to run Kibana against it.

I download Kibana from [here](https://www.elastic.co/downloads/kibana) which is version `5.1.1` When I try to connect to Elastic search it gives the following error

`[error][status][plugin:elasticsearch@5.1.1] Status change
d from yellow to red - This version of Kibana requires Elasticsearch v5.1.1 on a
ll nodes. I found the following incompatible nodes in your cluster: v2.3.5`

I have two questions

1. Which version of Kibana is compatible to Elasticsearch 2.3.5.?
2. Where can I download a Windows installable for that Kibana?

Comment: Only 5.x versions work with Elasticsearch 5.x... There is a **past releases** link on the download page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The 4.5 release of Kibana requires Elasticsearch 2.3 or later

The search bar in the Elastic site works pretty well.

Find related downloads - https://www.elastic.co/search?q=kibana+4.5&section=Downloads